# Using Facebook's Page Plugin in a ReactJS app

Tags: facebook, reactjs

As the title says: I'm struggling with the Facebook's page plugin; I've tried to put all the div provided by Facebook inside my app in React, but nothing happens.

Researching a little bit, I figured it out that the componentDidMount lifecycle have to be used. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the code of the plugin in the render function: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

In componentDidMount, call [FB.XFBML.parse()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse) to render the Plugin. Of course you have to make sure that the JavaScript SDK is loaded first.